# How to Update data in the dataGridview ONLY

Tags: c#, datagridview

My application imports a sheet from an excel file with only the header column names into a new dataGridView Table.  To keep it easy lets say the Column names are;  Name, City, State, Status.  I "hard code" the first 2 entries as   Jack, Detroit, MI, Missing; and Mike, Chicago, IL, Missing.  Next I import an XML file that adds more entries.  I have the code looking for the original 2 entries, if found, I want it to "update" or "re-edit" the Missing to Found.  (I want this to happen ONLY in the dataGridView Table.  The sql examples I'm finding are all aimed at updating the original database.  I want it to only update the dataGridView table.

This code is designed to update the excel file.

```
sql = "UPDATE " + myNameRange + " SET " + mySET + "' WHERE " + myWHERE + "'";
```

Is there a way I can do something like this only to change the data in the dataGridView?

Method to bring in sheets from excel

```
public static void loadData(string SheetName, DataGridView MyDataGrid, string filePathMain)
{
    string pathCon = "Provider=Microsoft.Ace.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source=" + filePathMain + ";Extended Properties=\"Excel 8.0; HDR=YES;IMEX=3;READONLY=FALSE\";";
    OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(pathCon);
    OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("select * from [" + SheetName + "]", conn);
    conn.Open();
    OleDbDataAdapter myDataAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd);
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    myDataAdapter.Fill(dt);
    //MessageBox.Show( dt.Rows.Count.ToString());
    MyDataGrid.Tag = dt.Rows.Count.ToString();
    MyDataGrid.DataSource = dt;
    OleDbCommand updateCmd = new OleDbCommand("UPDATE [" + SheetName + "]");
    myDataAdapter.UpdateCommand = updateCmd;
    conn.Close();
}
```

Here I'm hard coding the data into the table.  This works.

```
DataTable dt = ((DataGridView)TC).DataSource as DataTable;


DataRow row0 = dt.NewRow();
row0["Name"] = "Jack";
row0["Status"] = "MISSING";
dt.Rows.Add(row0);

DataRow row1 = dt.NewRow();
row1["Name"] = "Mike";
row1["Status"] = "MISSING";
dt.Rows.Add(row1);
```

Comment: Is there a key you could use that's in the excel sheet?

Comment: I'm pretty new to programming.  Is a Key referencing a row?  In excel it is only the column headers, nothing else. It has to be this way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`dgvThing.DataSource` will give you the data that is bound to your `DataGridView` and you can minipulate this without modifying your original data source i.e. the excel file.

Edit: In this case, you would loop through the rows to find your person and update their status like so.

```
DataTable dt = ((DataGridView)TC).DataSource as DataTable;
foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
{
    if (row["Name"].Equals("Jack"))
        row["Status"] = "Found";
}
```

Comment: `DataSource` will return whatever you have originaly saved to it. So, if you saved your excel data as an Array it will come out as an Array, but you will have to cast it to use it. Ex. `((string[])dgvThing.DataSource)[1] = "Stuff"`.

Comment: is the [1] referencing the second row?  Assuming [0] would be the first row?  I need to reference the changing of the Missing to Found by the First name...  In my code, I'm saying if the first name == to Mike, then I need to go up to where Mike is and change Missing to Found.

Comment: Yes, `[1]` is reffering to the second row of data. In order to update that i would need to know how your data is stored into the `DataGridView` initially. Custom class? String? OLEDB? Because that will drasticly change how you go about acessing that 4th column of `Missing` to change the value.

Comment: I've added some more information up top.. I'm showing the code on how I load the data from the excel sheet into my dataGridView.

Comment: Afteryou update the sheet, simply call the routine again to bind it to the dgv.

Comment: As the code goes through the XML file.. it finds a Jack Detroit MI...  I need to my code to say.. "Ok, go to the Name column and find Mike, then go over to the Status column and change it from Missing to Found.

Comment: Thanks so much for the help AustinH100! Huge help!